# how i can write test for function return json data in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I have a function it return json data

```
return response()->json([
  'status' => 'OK',
  'data' => [
      'id' => $dataInfo->id,
  ],
]);
```

how I can solve this in testing for function ?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/http-tests#testing-json-apis

Example (add this in your unit test file):

```
$this->json('post', 'your/route')
     ->assertStatus(200)
     ->assertJson([
        'status' => 'OK',
     ]);
```

Comment: PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Argument #1 (No Value) of PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertJson() must be a string

I got this

Answer (score 1):

You can use `assertJson()` and other similar methods in Laravel 5.4:

```
 $this->json('put', 'api/some-url')
      ->assertStatus(200)
      ->assertJson([
          'status' => 'OK',
          'data' => [
              'id' => 5,
          ]
      ]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/http-tests#testing-json-apis

In Laravel 5.3 and lower, JSON testing methods are different. Mostly used one is `seeJson()`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/application-testing#testing-json-apis

Comment: @flower usually you're expecting some specified data while testing response.

Comment: i try it :) but i got this error 

PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Argument #1 (No Value) of PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertJson() must be a string